# Issue with Oracle packages and types becoming invalid when compiled through ODP .NET

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, automation, odp.net

## Background

I am trying to compile types and packages on an Oracle database using ODP.NET.

## The Issue

When I read the contents of my .pks files in C# and run that command using `ExecuteNonQuery`/`ExecuteNonQueryAsync`, the compile sequence appears to work just fine. The command executes, however the compiled objects are in an invalid state (see screenshot from SQL Developer below).

[image: This is a screenshot of the package state after the C# program attempted to create types and packages automatically]

If I manually go into SQL Developer, right click on the invalid type and click compile, it works with no issues. I don't have to edit any code, there are no warning or errors thrown. (see pictures below.)

1. Find the invalid package or type
   [image]
2. Right click and compile the type/package
   [image]
3. No errors are thrown, the type/package compiles with no issues
   [image]

Because these steps consistently work I added `ALTER TYPE/PACKAGE name_of_type_or_package COMPILE;` to all of my scripts to see if it would remedy the situation.

## What I've Tried

I have tried the following to remedy the problem:

1. Changing `\r\n` line endings to `\r`
2. Attempting to wrap my code in `BEGIN END;`
3. Attempting to wrap my code in `BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE END;`
4. Using just `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`
5. Stripping the final `;` off of my definition files.
6. Changing `\r\n` to `spaces`

I have also tried a number of other fixes, but I can't get anything to work.

## What Works

After I've run my program, if I go to the database and right click the invalid object and then select compile, the code compiles just fine.

If I run the script directly from Oracle SQL Developer using `@C:\FilePath` the types and procedures compile just fine.

## Question

What can I do to remedy this situation where my code is being compiled in an invalid state from ODP .NET?

### Reference

For reference, I have included the code from the `.pks` file I am attempting to run.

#### meta_data_row Permutation 1

```
DROP TYPE grid_report_metadata_row FORCE
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE grid_report_metadata_row AS OBJECT
(
    line_number NUMBER,
    report_signature VARCHAR2(32),
    group_name VARCHAR2(32),
    display_group_name VARCHAR2(32),
    metadata_name VARCHAR2(64),
    metadata VARCHAR2(256)
);
ALTER TYPE grid_report_metadata_row COMPILE
```

#### meta_data_row Permutation 2

```
DROP TYPE grid_report_metadata_row FORCE;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE grid_report_metadata_row AS OBJECT
(
    line_number NUMBER,
    report_signature VARCHAR2(32),
    group_name VARCHAR2(32),
    display_group_name VARCHAR2(32),
    metadata_name VARCHAR2(64),
    metadata VARCHAR2(256)
);
ALTER TYPE grid_report_metadata_row COMPILE;
```

#### meta_data_row Permutation 3

```
DROP TYPE grid_report_metadata_row FORCE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE grid_report_metadata_row AS OBJECT
(
    line_number NUMBER,
    report_signature VARCHAR2(32),
    group_name VARCHAR2(32),
    display_group_name VARCHAR2(32),
    metadata_name VARCHAR2(64),
    metadata VARCHAR2(256)
);
/
ALTER TYPE grid_report_metadata_row COMPILE
```

Comment: It is normal for code containing errors to be invalid following compilation. Address the compilation errors and retry.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson The code has no errors. When I run the code from Oracle SQL Developer using `@C:\FilePath` it runs with no issues.

Comment: Additionally, I don't have to modify any of the packages to make the compile properly. I just right click them in Oracle SQL Developer, select recompile and they work. So why am I not able to run them from ODP .NET despite following the advice of a number of different sources on Stack Overflow and the internet?

Comment: Compilation with errors doesn't cause a script failure. What are the errors anyway?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson No errors are being thrown. The packages are just invalidated. The script runs successfully, but the packages and types are invalidated.

Comment: Perhaps there is some dependency that requires a recompilation to clear.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Any idea where or how I could find what that dependency might be?

Comment: What tool are you using to execute the CREATE statements? SQL Developer?. What ORA error do you receive when you execute them with ODP.NET? Please show the code in ODP.NET where you set up and make the call. User Defined Types require special handling by ODP.NET and other client libs so I would initially use packages with scalar types until you get that working to keep things simple.

Comment: For an intro into using User Defined Types with ODP.NET please see this: https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:0::::P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:10199,1

Comment: @ChristianShay I have looked throught he article you provided me with on user defined types and I can say that we're not using the database that way. Once again, I'm not getting any error in Oracle or ODP.NET. The code executes with no issues, but once the code has been executed the type and the packages involve are invalidated. I have tested all of my `.PKS` directly against the database using SQL Developer, the run with no errors. Each package and type is defined in its own `.PKS` file. I read in the text and run the text line by line using ODP.NET when my program runs.

Comment: @ChristianShay The overall goal of this is to automate the compilation and creation of the types needed by the an in house C# program. One of the tags for this question is automation. If I have to manually run commands against the database, then I am not achieving my goal. I can manually compile the packages and types with no issues.

Comment: I understand. We still haven't seen your code though. I assume you are properly handling the exceptions that could be thrown and there are none? One idea might be to try to install the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio and then try to execute the same things inside "Query Window" which uses ODP.NET underneath and see if it says theres an error.